# How can I call an Inherited function to execute when declared in child class

Tags: c#, oop, unity-game-engine

Take this sample code from Unity 3D

```
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour 
{
    void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {
       transform.postion = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, new Vector3(0, 1, 0), 5f * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the class `Enemy` inherits from `MonoBehavior` which contains the `Start` and the `Update` methods. All I have to do is put in my own code there, but, I would like to know how to create a similar thing say for building a Chat API in Java for instance, where I would lay it out to the consumers to just access my base class and would have a function like "Update" that was executed every second without them having to manually code a while loop.

How can I create a base class function that can be called automatically when the child class declares it? I am open to any programming language anyone could answer it with, all i want to know is the logic behind this.

Comment: This is way too broad for Stack Overflow. Unity internally uses (most likely, cannot verify) Reflection in order to determine whether `Start` and other methods were declared. There's nothing built into c# that allows you to do this, though.

Comment: There is no such thing as a method that gets called just by being declared. Just like there's no such thing as car that gets driven just because it's built. Until a method is called it does nothing, ever.

Comment: @ScottHannen Yes, i understand you sir,  am thinking it got called during runtime by Unity. Think about it like the JApplet, the draw() method is called once every frame. What i want to know is that processes name so i can research it. Honestly its like one of the things I haven't gotten to in programming.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Understood!

Comment: You can use polymorphism. This was how XNA did it. Unity opted for a manifest style system. At compile time, the MonoBehaviour script is scanned for specific methods and then it somehow marks them with what methods are implemented. No reflection there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base class could have a timer created in it's constructor that is setup to call an abstract method on a 1s interval.

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    private Timer _timer;

    protected BaseClass()
    {
        _timer = new Timer();
        _timer.Tick += (sender, args) => 
       {
          Console.WriteLine("Calling Update."); 
          Update();
       };
        _timer.Interval = 1000;
        _timer.Start();            
    }

    protected abstract void Update();
}

public class InheritedClass : BaseClass
{
    protected override void Update()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Update was called.");
    }
}
```

You can use this in a console app to demo the functionality.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var inheritedClass = new InheritedClass();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I get where your coming from, this logic I can relate to and its very Understandable. Thank you sir for your answer.

Comment: Instead of each class having its timer,  a new class registers to a manager then manager runs a foreach on the collection.

Comment: I agree @Everts. Wasn't going that in depth but was just showing an easy example of how a method could be called on a specific interval without the person using your framework needing to write that code.